# Homomorphic Encryption CKKS scheme, Encoding: canonical embeding discretization

Tags: homomorphic-encryption

I'm trying to understand CKKS (non bootstrappable) and I'm struggling with the encoding part.
I'm using the original paper , ["Homomorphic Encryption for Arithmetic of Approximate Numbers
"](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-70694-8_15), also this notes ["Lattices, Homomorphic Encryption, and CKKS"](https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.2205.03511)
and this [blog](https://blog.openmined.org/ckks-explained-part-2-ckks-encoding-and-decoding/).

I have four questions (will have sense after):

1. If Im right of the projection.
2. The final steps are trivials?
3. Why when we round the coefficients we get the coefficients of the polynomial.
4. Why they use a "special" algorithm for rounding that is random.

**Context**:
So, given a vector $z\in \mathbb{C}^{N/2}$ they use the canonical embedding $\sigma^{-1}$ to map it to $\mathcal{R} =\mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^N+1)$.
Basically $\sigma^{-1}:z\to\mathcal{R}$.
First they expand z mirroring it with the complex conjugates so $\pi^{-1}(z)\in\mathbb{H}\subset \mathbb{C}^{N}$. With $\mathbb{H}$ the set of all complex vector with this conjugate mirror property.
Because this $\pi^{-1}(z)$ may not live in the space of $\sigma(\mathcal{R})$, they discretize it by projecting this the base of $\sigma(\mathcal{R})$.
Up to here, all good.

For this they take the basis vectors $\alpha_i$, and project z to it.
**First question**, this is correct?:

\begin{equation}
z_{proj} = \sum_{i=0}^{N-1} \frac{<z,\alpha_i>}{<\alpha_i,\alpha_i>}\alpha_i
\end{equation}

Where <a,b> is the Hermitian inner product.
However they perform an rounding algorithm ("coordinate-wise random rounding") for each $\frac{<z,\alpha_i>}{<\alpha_i,\alpha_i>}$.

And finally, if we call $A$ to the matrix that has as columns the basis vectors $\alpha_i$, $\lfloor x \rceil$ as x rounded with the algorithm and consider the vector $z' = (\lfloor<z, \alpha_1>/<\alpha_1,\alpha_1>\rceil,..., \lfloor<z, \alpha_n>/<\alpha_n,\alpha_n>\rceil)$.
We can rewrite the projection as:

\begin{equation}
z_{roundProj} = Az'
\end{equation}

So if then we want to apply $\sigma^{-1}(z')$ (get the coefficients of the polynomial $\gamma_i$), is basically to solve the system of linear equations:

\begin{equation}
A\gamma=z_{roundProj} \rightarrow \gamma=A^{-1}z_{roundProj} = A^{-1}Az'=z' \rightarrow \gamma=z
\end{equation}

So, the steps that involves to multiply A with  $z'$ to "complete" the  projection to then solve the system of linear equations is not necessary. **Second question**, this is correct?

**Third question**, if this is correct, why when we round up each $\frac{<z,\alpha_i>}{<\alpha_i,\alpha_i>}$ we get each coefficient of the polynomial.

**Fourth question** why we need a special algorithm for rounding and not the usual ones (to the nearest integer) if in this stage there is not issue with security?

Answer (score 1):

This is only an answer for the 4th question.

While we could apply the (deterministic) map $x\mapsto \lfloor x\rceil$, it has some issues.
In particular, the error $e := \lfloor x\rceil - x$ from applying it depends on $x$, which is not great.

Coordinate-wise random round fixes this.
In particular, it satisfies the correctness property that

$$\mathbb{E}[\mathsf{randround}(x)] = x$$

While there is non-trivial variance (i.e. the rounding algorithm is not deterministic), this is perhaps a slightly better situation to be in (and additionally, the variance may be independent of $x$ --- I would have to check though).

Comment: Obviously I'm new in Crypto, but why is not great that that error depends on x? The encoding part I thought that was not where the security came in place.

Comment: It doesn't, but when analyzing error growth you then either need to apply worst-case bounds on $x$ (needlessly lossy), or appeal to heuristics. Randomized rounding let's you do provable analysis. I think it's typically larger than experimentally observed errors, e.g. people just use the heuristics. But if you want fully provable stuff randomized rounding can be useful.